# Interthread communication between threads with no objects in common

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I am developing an instant messaging server and I have at any given time *n* spawned threads due to *n* connected clients. At any given time, any given spawned thread needs to be able to communicate with any other spawned thread by means of sending data (data can be anything, doesn't matter).

I have looked at solutions with Queues and Pipes; however, they all rely on a thread such as the main one to create a queue and/or pipe object and pass that to the constructors of the two spawned threads. In my scenario, all my threads have nothing in common and do not share any references to the same objects in memory or anything like that.

How can I possibly set up some kind of communication channel between two threads that exhibit the behaviours of the ones I have described?

Comment: Whatever you will use, it will be something that has to be created before the threads are started and it will be a kind of object they have in common. But what’s the problem with that? There definitely *is* someone starting the threads, they do not come out of nothing…

Comment: Spawn a communicator thread? I don't understand how threads in the same program are isolated I'm that type of scenario? Using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you need to create a "Broker" object. Threads would connect to this broker, who would save a reference to the client, so that it could invoke callback methods on it. This is a very common patter, Publish/Subscribe.

Comment: Hi, is this class under the official Java API. If so what is its package ?

Comment: No, this is more of a general software pattern to use to solve the problem you describe. Have a look at http://mqtt.org/ for a good example. Facebook built their messanger product using MQTT

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that for two threads to share data between them, there must be some sort of shared object between the threads.  I don't think you can avoid that.

So the question becomes: how to share an object when the producer and the consumer don't know about each other?

Well, I would be willing to wager that there is **some** actor/class/process/whatever in your system which knows of both the producers and consumers.

```
class BunchOfWorkDoer {
  public void doWork() {
    BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);
    createAndStartProducer(q);
    createAndStartConsumer(q); 
    createAndStartConsumer(q); 
  }
}
```

However, if the above is not practical, you can invert the relationship, and have producers and consumers "reach out" and get the queue to use.  The basic pattern:

```
// "public static" is just the simplest way to express the idea. YMMV
class Broker {
   public static BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);
}
// producer impl is similar, as you'd expect
class ConsumerImpl implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    BlockingQueue queue = Broker.queue;
    // do your work
  }
}
```

In the system you describe, the Broker might be a class which allowed threads (connections) to register a queue based on some key (like the user's IM handle)

```
class Broker {
   private static ConcurrentMap<String,BlockingQueue> queues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   public static BlockingQueue findQueue(String name) {
     return queues.get(name);
   }
   // lots of choices to make in the design of this broker ....
   public static BlockingQueue registerQueue(String name, BlockingQueue q) {
     return queues.putIfAbsent(name, q);
   }
   public static void removeQueue(String name) {
     return queues.remove(name);
   }
}
```

When a connection is established, that connection's thread registers a queue so others can communicate with it, and a thread which wants to communicate to another thread would look up the queue by name (using the broker) and pass messages through that queue.

Oh, and you might consider SynchronousQueue

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah that helps quite a bit actually. I suppose the number of entries in the broker would get quite large however so I'm not sure if there is anything I can do about that